# AWS Step Functions: size exceeding the maximum number of bytes service limit

Tags: aws-step-functions

I have a 2 steps state machine in AWS Step Functions.
The first function does a query in a MySql database and sends to the second one a JSON.

I am getting the following error:

```
The state/task 'xxxx' returned a result with a size exceeding the maximum number of bytes service limit.
```

As per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70790099/aws-step-functions-states-datalimitexceeded-error) and the Step Function [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/limits-overview.html) the `Maximum input or output size for a task, state, or execution` is `262,144 bytes of data as a UTF-8 encoded string`.

I am testing the size of the JSON I am sending

```
const size = Buffer.byteLength(JSON.stringify(data))
console.log('dataSize:', size)
```

and the size is `INFO dataSize: 29444` in the console log.
It is much lower than allowed based on the documentation.

If I change the query to fetch less data it works.

Some idea on what could possible be?

Comment: You should check both the input and output size of each steps.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I have the same problem, the concurrent Lambdas in the Dynamic Parallelism step succeeds, but getting this message for Type: Map

Comment: no, I remember that I changed my approach. After the query I sent the chunks of data to a S3 bucket and attached a lambda function to process that chunk of data and then delete the file after the processing.